# check if html attribute exist and has right value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a better way for checking an attribute for:

1. it exist. so value must be false if attribute doesn't exist
2. Value is correct (boolean)

```js
var isOwner = false;
    if ($(selectedItem).is('[data-isOwner="True"]') || $(selectedItem).is('[data-isOwner="true"]')) {
        isOwner = true;
    } else {
        isOwner = false;
    }
```

Now I need to check for *'True'* and *'true'*...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the value stored in *data-isOwner* to lower case and only compare the value to 'true'.

```
if (($(selectedItem).attr ('data-isOwner') || '').toLowerCase () == 'true')
```

---

The above use of *`<wanted-value> || ''`* will make it so that if the *selectedItem* doesn't have the attribute *data-isOwner* the expression will result in an empty string, on which you can call *toLowerCase* without errors.

Without this little hack you'd have to manually check so that the attribute is indeed present, otherwise you'd run into a *runtime-error* when trying to call *toLowerCase* on an *undefined* object.

---

If you find the previously mentioned solution confusing you could use something as

```
var attr_value = $(selectedItem).attr ('data-isOwner');

if (typeof(attr_value) == 'string' && attr_value.toLowerCase () == 'true') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I like your approache. Can it also be checked typesafe? I set the property with ASP .NET MVC4 and C# so it is a boolean. Should I parse the lowercase to a boolean? and then compare with: === true?

Comment: I think every values always comes out at string unless you parse it into something in your JS.

Comment: @LockTar if you store a value inside an element's attribute it will be  of type string when using `$(selector).attr (key)` or the equivalent, if you want it to be handled differently you'll need to provide your own wrapper around the getter.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I only used === because it should be saver then == 'true'